# How to make a bending animation with silverlight

Tags: silverlight, animation, effect

Any idea how to make an animation like used on the link below? I want to make a paper effect with animation on silverlight but dont know how to do. The first came to my mind is making a gif or video by some 3d medelling programs like 3dsmax but that is a trick not a solution :) Or pixel shader effects but it's a complex way i think.

http://www.templatemonster.com/silverlight-templates/31855.html

thaks.

Comment: That animation in your link is very hard on the eyes. I can feel a migraine coming on from only 30 seconds of clicking those options! *Do you really want to make your users ill?* :) Try come up with something a little more subtle.

Comment: @HiTechMagic sorry for migraine :) But i really wonder how to ;)